# dV of differential disc forming sphere vs dA of differential ring forming spherical shell

Tags: integration, volume, surfaces

I am trying to derive the results for the gravitational field for a solid sphere and a spherical shell.  In both cases the sphere's radius is $R$ and integration is performed with the origin of the $x$ axis located a the sphere/shell center.  For the solid sphere a differential disc is integrated from while for the spherical shell a differential ring is used.

**Disc**

The differential volume of our differential disc of radius $r$ is written
$$dV = 2 \pi r^2 dx$$
where the origin of the $x$ passes through the sphere's center.  Integrating this from $x = -R$ to $x = R$ will give the volume of a sphere
$$\int dV = \int_{x=-R}^{x=+R} 2 \pi r^2 dx$$
The differential disc's radius $r$ equals $\sqrt{R^2-x^2}$ so this becomes
$$V = \int_{x=-R}^{x=+R} 2 \pi (R^2 - x^2) dx$$
Performing this integration we get the expected result $4 \pi R^3/3$.

**Ring**

The differential surface area of a disc of radius $r$ is written
$$dA = \textrm{perimeter} \times \textrm{width} = [2\pi \sin(\theta) R] \times [R d\theta]$$
where $\theta$ is the angle formed between the $x$-axis and sphere radius connected to the top of the ring. Integrating this from $\theta = 0$ to $\theta = \pi$ gives the surface area of a sphere
$$\int dA = \int_{\theta = 0}^{\theta = \pi} 2\pi R^2 sin(\theta) d\theta$$
Performing this integration we get the expected result $4\pi R^2$.

**Statement**

I understand how each of the above work and are derived.  What I do not understand is why in the disc case we can integrate over $x$ but for the ring we must integrate over $\theta$.

**Question**

Why can we use the volume of a cylinder to get $dV$ for the differential disc BUT we can NOT use the surface area of a cylinder to get $dA$ for the differential ring?

That is, we can NOT mimic what we used to find $dV$ and write
$$dA = 2 \pi r \times dx$$
replace $r = \sqrt{R^2 - x^2}$ and then integrate from $x = -R$ to $x = +R$?  Doing that integration does NOT give $4 \pi R^2$.  Am I just missing something obvious?

Comment: You could, but you would have to tage a truncated cone instead of a cylinder, to take the orientation into account. The intuitive idea behind these integrals is, the error is an order smaller, so that when we integrate it amounts to nothing. With a cylinder to approximate locally a sphere that would not hold.

Comment: I can certainly see that each is an approximation but I assumed in the limit they all would reduce to the same result.  So are you saying the error using $dV = 2 \pi r^2 dx$ is smaller than the error using $dA = 2\pi r dx$?

Comment: This question has been asked and answered numerous times on this site, so you should search for surface area and arclength. Start by understanding why you cannot take $ds = dx$ when you do arclength of a a curve $y=f(x)$ in the plane.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin:  Thanks.  Found them.  Came to the same conclusions regarding curvature.  Thanks again for bothering to respond.  So few people seem to care enough to help.  This site has gotten worse over the years.

Comment: LD, it’s gotten worse because it’s overrun with people posting verbatim homework and exam questions with literally zero effort. It’s beyond frustrating. Your question is a good one. If it hadn’t appeared so many times, I would have written a thorough answer.  This is in fact something that bothered me many years ago, when I was first learning calculus.

Comment: Humbling to learn stuff after decades of using/teaching.  Amazing that it is unexplained in most sources.  Not obvious until it becomes obvious.